# How to send a recurring event from Outlook to Google Calendar

Tags: vba, outlook, google-calendar-api, rrule

I have some Outlook VBA code which executes when I add an event to my Outlook calendar.  The code makes use of the google calendar API to send the event information to google.  Google them updates my google calendar.  I also have code which, when I delete an event from my Outlook calendar, will send a DELETE to google through the calendar API.  Google then deletes the event from my google calendar.  This code works perfectly.

Now I need to write the VBA code which will send recurring event data to google.  Is there a simple way to send this information? Is there an online service that I can send information to and have an RRule string generated? Do I have to build the RRule string manually?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with Office365 account you may consider using the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) directly without involving client applications like Outlook. For the Exchange on-premise you may consider using Exchange Web Services, see [Start using web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/start-using-web-services-in-exchange) for more information.

If you need to end up with a client-side solution you may consider creating a VSTO based add-in (COM add-in) which can sync everything with your system. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) to get started quickly. VBA was not designed for distributing solutions on multiple machines.

Comment: The end user will be using the Outlook app on his phone.

Comment: VBA doesn't make sense in that case (as well as COM add-ins). That is for desktop applications only. Consider using Graph API or EWS.